# Xamarin ASP mvc 4 action with parameters not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mono, action, xamarin

I have these actions:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index ()
        {
            ViewData ["Message"] = "Welcome to ASP.NET MVC on Mono!";
            return View ();
        }


        public ActionResult Pages (string test)
        {
            ViewBag.Message = test;
            return View ();
        }


    }
```

The pages action is not working. I get an error 500:

```
System.TypeLoadException
Could not load type 'System.Web.UnvalidatedRequestValuesBase' from assembly 'System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.

Description: HTTP 500.Error processing request.

Details: Non-web exception. Exception origin (name of application or object): System.Web.Mvc.
Exception stack trace:
at System.Web.Mvc.FormValueProviderFactory.GetValueProvider (System.Web.Mvc.ControllerContext controllerContext) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 at System.Web.Mvc.ValueProviderFactoryCollection.GetValueProvider (System.Web.Mvc.ControllerContext controllerContext) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.get_ValueProvider () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.GetParameterValue (System.Web.Mvc.ControllerContext controllerContext, System.Web.Mvc.ParameterDescriptor parameterDescriptor) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.GetParameterValues (System.Web.Mvc.ControllerContext controllerContext, System.Web.Mvc.ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker+<>c__DisplayClass21.<BeginInvokeAction>b__19 (System.AsyncCallback asyncCallback, System.Object asyncState) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

If I remove the parameter from that action is working fine.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

p.s. I don't have any routes defined yet.

Comment: I also have this problem. Did you discover a fix?

Comment: Hey mate. I quit trying. I got Microsoft visual studio.

Comment: For anyone stumbling on this probelm: You may be using the incorrect version of ASP MVC. NuGet offers MVC 5, and using this version with controller parameters will trigger the error mentioned in this question. ASP MVC 4 doesn't show up in searches unless you search for "ASP MVC Legacy". Switching to this version resolved the issue.

Comment: I have the same problem (mono 3.4.0 and MVC4). I am sure that I use MVC4: 4.0.20710.0). What package version do you use rooney?

Comment: can you provide access to a sample project? it appears that either the correct version of 'System.Web' is not available or it is configured wrong in either the main web.config or the config file in the Views directory

Comment: The linked questions doesnt have an answer - but it offers a clue as to why the type is not found (Not yet implemented) - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23884792/mvc5-project-run-monodevelop-but-mono-terminal-command-cannot-run

Answer (score 7):

*Using newest mono(3.6.1) doesn't resolve issue.*
What helps is:
**If you're using 5.X NuGet Microsoft ASP.NET MVC package, downgrade to MVC 4 is required.**

### Steps:

1. Uninstall following NuGet packages(order is important):

   - Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages
   - Microsoft.AspNet.Razor
   - Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc
2. Install [Microsoft ASP.NET MVC 4](https://www.nuget.org/packages/aspnetmvc) NuGet package.

### Errors that may occur:

- *The view 'Index' or its master was not found.*

  - Solution - change version of `System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc` in **/Views/Web.Config** in `factoryType` attribute of `host` node to **4.0.0.0**.
    So line looks like this:

`<host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />`

- *System.InvalidOperationException Conflicting versions of ASP.NET Web Pages detected: specified version is “3.0.0.0”, but the version in bin is “2.0.0.0”. To continue, remove files from the application’s bin directory or remove the version specification in web.config.*

  - Solution - change `webpages:Version` to 2.0.0.0 in Root directory/**Web.Config** so it looks like this:
    `<add key=”webpages:Version” value=”2.0.0.0” />`

Then you can use parameters in controller actions.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work for me. Trying to remove WebPages-package, I get the error `Unable to uninstall 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages 3.2.0' because 'Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc 5.2.0' depends on it.`. I tried removing the Mvc-package and then removing the rest, which works, but when i install MVC again i have the very same issue :(

Comment: @AntonGildebrand You have to install MVC 4 Package, not 5. MVC 5 doesn't work in Mono yet. https://www.nuget.org/packages/aspnetmvc - MVC4.

Comment: @Daniel, how do I install MVC 4 package in monodevelop? there is no package manager console and i can't find a way to specify the version in package manager gui.

Comment: @th1rdey3 Could you please look at https://github.com/mrward/monodevelop-nuget-extensions ? It adds Package Manager console. You should be able to install `AspNetMvc -Version 4.0.20710`. Today https://github.com/mono/mono/pull/1163 - pull request  allowing MVC 5.2 to run was merged to Mono so soon you should be able to run MVC5.

Comment: I tried following the isntructions.. but not working. can you tell from which version of mono will MVC5.2 be supported? I am using 3.10 now.

Comment: @th1rdey3 I don't know that but you can get it from git now and try to build and you will get this feature. But I think Mono build on Debian is broken...

Comment: I followed the instruction given [here](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/getting-started/install/linux/) to install mono. Is it broken now?

Comment: @th1rdey3 Linux build is broken. I'm 99% sure. : / We have to wait until someone can try these changes.

Comment: @Daniel Any news yet? I cannot bind parameters now after following the suggestions above.

Comment: @user2609980 Unfortunately I don't follow recent Mono changes. Mono master branch on Github has everything to run MVC5.2 according to https://github.com/mono/mono/pull/1163 But this branch might still be broken on Linux...

Comment: @Daniel Thanks for your reply. I have used a query string parameter and that works properly.

Comment: I wasn't able to install the packages for MVC 4 (or 3, for that matter). None of the suggested search criterias worked, including "_ASP.NET MVC Legacy_". I managed to get them using directly the [nuget.exe](http://nuget.org/nuget.exe) command line utility. I ran `mono nuget.exe install Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc -Version 4.0.30506` in the packages directory under my project. Strangely enough, after I did this, I went back to the Add Packages dialog in monodevelop and the first search result for "mvc" was ASP.NET MVC 4 ... go figure.

Answer (score 1):

This is embarrassing, but here is my workaround until Mono updates System.Web:

```
public ActionResult Index() //string app_id, string session_id, int surah_id, int ayat_id)
{
    string app_id = Request["app_id"];
    string session_id = Request["session_id"];
    int surah_id = Int32.Parse(Request["surah_id"]);
    int ayat_id = Int32.Parse(Request["ayat_id"]);

    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error as OP in my `MVC`-project. (Currently using `Xamarin` on a `Mac`) I'm using Microsoft Exchange WebServices, and I found out that downgrading this package solved my problem. I downgraded the `Microsoft.Exchange.Webservices` package from `2.2` to `1.2`.