# MVC5 project run Monodevelop, but Mono terminal/command cannot run

Tags: mono, monodevelop

I have developed Asp MVC5 project on VS2012.Now i need this projet run on linux with Mono.

I have installed Mono 3.2.3 and Monodevelop 4.2.5.

I successfully build MVC5 project with Monodevelop, and it works smoothly for me when I run with debug/without debug on Monodevelop.

But when i deploy this project using Monodevelop. And using Mono command (xsp4). 
Many errors occured. For example: 
System.TypeLoadException
Could not load type 'System.Web.UnvalidatedRequestValuesBase' from assembly 'System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.

Anyone have same problem with me ? I think Monodevelop using Mono for running ? This problem took me 3 days. But now, i still cannot solve this problems.
Please let me know why ? and how to solve this problem.
Thanks all.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that when you say it runs with MonoDevelop you are running this on Windows and the error only occurs when you run it on Linux using Mono.

Looking at the Mono source code and the [status page](http://go-mono.com/status/status.aspx?reference=4.5&profile=4.5&assembly=System.Web) it seems that the [System.Web.UnvalidatedRequestValuesBase](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.unvalidatedrequestvaluesbase.aspx) is not yet implemented on Mono.