# FormsAuthentication on mono/ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, mono, monodevelop

I am aware that this is a [known problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21827225/xamarin-asp-mvc-4-action-with-parameters-not-working) , that trying to use FormsAuthentication on mono leads to `Could not load type System.Web.UnvalidatedRequestValuesBase` exception. My question is: has there been any way to work around the issue?

The reason why I am asking is: most of the authorization stuff does work. I am getting redirected to logon form and such. The only thing I can not do is `FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage` or `FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie`. There's got to be a way to get around that, otherwise what's the use of all the framework xamarin folks expended if you can't actually login?

For example: maybe there is some other logon module which works like forms authentication module, but is implemented differently?

Comment: Can you create a forms ticket manually and then encrypt it and send in a cookie? Neither of the two methods is not required for that.

Comment: @WiktorZychla do you have a code snippet?..

Comment: `var ticket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(...); var encrypted = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt( ticket ); this.Response.AppendCookie( new HttpCookie( FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, encrypted ) );`

Comment: @WiktorZychla tried to do this with different variations, same error. Initially thought this error happens because it tries to load class `FormsAuthentication`, but referencing `FormsAuthentication.DefaultUrl` is ok. Also determined that downgrading MVC to version 2.0 helps

Comment: Xamarin offerings don't include ASP.NET, so don't mix those two in your question (edit it please)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, this issue is not happening in MVC2 project as created by monodevelop. I guess this is how FormsAuthentication could possibly be used. I would keep this question unanswered in case someone can post a better answer.